# Issue properly removing property binding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm struggling to find a proper way to disable property binding in WPF. I have an `Image` and I want to disable/enable binding to its `Source` property based on application settings. The problem is that even when I set `Source` to `Null` I can still see that WPF is accessing my model for that binding.

Here's my example:

```
<Image>
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{x:Null}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowBackgroundImage, Source={x:Static pui:App.Current}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding Game.BackgroundImageObject, IsAsync=True, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

I have verified that `Source` is being properly set to `Null` based on `ShowBackgroundImage` value, but WPF still calls getter for `BackgroundImageObject` when it changes, even if `Source` is already null. The interesting thing is that it only happens when I change `ShowBackgroundImage` while the application is already running. If default state is `False` then biding seems to be disabled properly, but once I set `ShowBackgroundImage` to True and then back to False it stops working properly (Source is null but calls to BackgroundImageObject are still being made).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Setting the ShowBackgroundImage to true should cause the getter of BackgroundImageObject to get called, shouldn't it?

Comment: It does, the problem is that it's still being called after I change it to False.

Comment: You'd should clear the binding programatically instead of trying to use a DataTrigger in XAML.

Comment: Have you made sure that `App.Current` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` properly, and that `ShowBackgroundImage` fires `OnPropertyChanged` with proper property name?

Comment: `ShowBackgroundImage` binding is not a problem. As I said in original post, `Source` property is being set properly based on value of `ShowBackgroundImage` (I have verified that via Visual Tree debugger). The problem is that when I switch `ShowBackgroundImage` from True to False, it sets `Source` to null properly, but there are still calls being made to get value of `BackgroundImageObject`.